# Is there a dataset on existing flow of people between US cities?(could be car, bus, train or plane)

Tags: usa, traffic

I am working on a project and would love to see in a year how many people go from one city in the US to another. I know this is fairly extensive and might require putting together multiple sets.

Comment: are you looking for trips, or relocation?  I've seen cities report on changes in population, but I don't know that I've seen a 'where people moved to (or came from)'  breakdown, other than for disasters like Hurricane Katrina.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

review the codebooks for

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20household%20travel%20survey%20%28nhts%29

and

http://www.asdfree.com/2012/12/analyze-american-community-survey-acs.html

nhts has day-to-day travel movement.  acs has migration info